# Date formats from device based on locale

Tags: ios, objective-c

As per my knowledge the date format will vary based on locale, 
Is there a way to read date-format from device's local settings for current date?

1. Whether the date format is "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy".
2. Time format is "h:mm a" or something else.
3. The AM/PM text is "AM" or "PM".

I can't afford for any third party libraries, please tell me whether this can be done using any apple classes.

**Edited:**

I don't want to set any formats, i just want to retrieve it from device based on locale.

say, here in my country the date format is dd/MM/yyyy in some part of the word its MM/dd/yyyy i want to get this format.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Use NSDateFormatter,set the style,it should use the user's locale formats. Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought, this would be just a simple fix. but on seeing some cool answers to this question, went curious about it. Here is my solution.

You can use NSDateFormatter for this, set the style to required formats

```
NSDateFormatterShortStyle   
NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
NSDateFormatterLongStyle
```

to know more please take a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Below is the snippet for you.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *dateformat = [dateFormatter dateFormat]; //M/d/yy
    NSString *amtext = [dateFormatter AMSymbol];       //AM
    NSString *pmtext = [dateFormatter PMSymbol];       //PM

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *timeformat = [dateFormatter dateFormat];   //h:mm a
```

it will use the user's locale formats. Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 13):

The method you're looking for is [`+[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW53).

This method is *specifically* for "localizing" a date format into a desired locale.

For example, if you want to know the user's preferred year-month-day format, you do:

```
NSString *fmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dMMMMy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Or if you want to know their preferred time format, you do:

```
NSString *fmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"jm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

You use this method when you need *the actual format string*.  If you just want to format a date according to the predefined styles (long, full, medium, short), then you use the constants as explained in a couple of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dateStyle and timeStyle of NSDateFormatter to achieve this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

//Only set what you want to show, if you set both, both will be included in the converted string

//This would be like dd/MM/yyyy depending on your locale 
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//This would be in hh:mm a
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

//Assuming you have a date instance already in hand
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: @Downvoter It would be nice to know what was wrong in this answer.

Comment: I feel the answer doesn't have anything wrong, curious to know why it is down voted. But regard to my question i don't need a dateString i just need the formats.

Answer (score 1):

1. Date format is depends upon how you are formatting your date object using **NSDateFormatter**. Date does not have a format unless you are formatting it.

   **Date formats**

   ```
   NSDateFormatterShortStyle   
   NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
   NSDateFormatterLongStyle
   ```

   or  use your own format

   ```
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];
   ```
2. Use the same date formatter to format the time also

   ```
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle]
   ```
3. You can set the AM/PM symbol as what ever you want

   ```
      [dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];  
      [dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current locale using:

```
  NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Or you can customize the date time using the following code for example:

```
NSDate * date = [m_DateTimePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//dd for date, MMMM: month, yyyy:year hh: hour, mm: minute a: AM/PM
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"];   
NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```