# Get Time Format (AM/PM or 24hrs) from Current Calendar / Locale

Tags: macos, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nslocale

I want to create my custom time format, but I need to know if the user's system preferences want 24 hour or AM/PM format. I've looked through NSCalendar and NSLocale but could not find it.

***UPDATE

Since the other question does not explicitly let us know how to get if the user wants 24-hour time style, I'm answering this question from 2 other questions I found. But still need confirmation if this will work ?

```
NSString *fmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"jm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];


BOOL is24HourStyle = [fmt rangeOfString:@"HH"].location != NSNotFound;
NSLog(@"%@", fmt);
NSLog(@"is 24 %@", is24HourStyle ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date formats from device based on locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481287/date-formats-from-device-based-on-locale) - See in particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16515219/1187415.

Comment: That answer helps, but does not explain how exactly know if its 24-hour time style or not. Still need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns:

- 'j' is a special purpose symbol for flexible date pattern generation. It requests the preferred hour format for the locale and must be replaced by 'h', 'H', 'K' or 'k'.
- 'h' and 'K' are symbols for 12-hour-cycle formats.
- 'H' and 'k' are symbols for 24-hour-cycle formats.

So to check for a 24-hour format, you should check if 'H' or 'k' occurs in the format
generated from the template:

```
NSString *fmt = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"jm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
BOOL is24HourStyle = [fmt rangeOfString:@"H"].location != NSNotFound
                  || [fmt rangeOfString:@"k"].location != NSNotFound;
```

I could not find a locale where the hour format is "k" or "K", but e.g. in the finish
locale, "jm" expands to "H.mm", therefore checking for "HH" is not correct.